# How to make chainable function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, chain, chainable

Lets imagine function like this:

```
function foo(x) {
    x += '+';
    return x;
}
```

Usage of it would be like:

```
var x, y;
x = 'Notepad';
y = foo(x);
console.log(y); // Prints 'Notepad+'.
```

I'm looking for a way to create function that's chainable with other functions.

Imagine usage:

```
var x, y;
x = 'Notepad';
y = x.foo().foo().toUpperCase(); // Prints 'NOTEPAD++'.
console.log(y);
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure, the trick is to return the object once you're done modifying it:

```
String.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this + "+";
}

var str = "Notepad";
console.log(str.foo().foo().toUpperCase());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/vyFek/

To make the method available on `String`, I'm modifying it's prototype. Be careful not to do this on `Object` though, as it can cause problems when enumerating over their properties.

Comment: it's a good idea to at least check for a property on the native types before adding it, i.e. `if ( !('foo' in String.prototype) ) {String.prototype.foo = function() {...} }`

Comment: If you want to extend an object without breaking the enumeration, use the (semi-modern) [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty): `Object.defineProperty( String.prototype, {value:function(){ return this+"+"; } } )`. By default the `enumerable` flag is set to `false`.

Comment: @keeganwatkins yes it is :). I assume the OP was only asking about strings as an example, so I kept the warnings to a minimum, but that's a good point.

Comment: Good solution, mine was too generic

Comment: Hmm... I have line like `this = this.replace(diacritics[i].letters, diacritics[i].base);`. It gives me 'Invalid assignment left-hand side.' in NetBeans.

Comment: [This](http://pastie.org/2678472) is how my code looks. Error is thrown on line #16.

Comment: You can't assign `this` in a string. Return the result instead. If you need to do multiple operations, store it in a temporary variable and return that instead. For example, `var str = this; str += "foo"; return str;`

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a chainable function attached to an object instead of to an String?

Comment: @Alvaro Yes. A string is an object.

Comment: @AlexTurpin I mean, an element taken from the DOM using `document.querySelector`

Comment: @Alvaro should be. I would create a separate SO question with your problem

Answer (score 11):

If I remember correctly, you can use "this" as a context of a function (object it belongs to) and return it to make the function chainable. In other words:

```
var obj = 
{
    f1: function() { ...do something...; return this;},
    f2: function() { ...do something...; return this;}
}
```

then you can chain the calls like `obj.f1().f2()`

Keep in mind, you won't be able to achieve what you are expecting by calling obj.f1().toUpperCase() - it will execute f1(), return "this" and will try to call obj.toUpperCase().

Comment: What would be the best practice to add .toUpperCase function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without messing with `String.prototype`, by returning an object similar to a string, with an additional method `foo()`. However, there are some downsides to this approach related to it not returning an actual string.

```js
// Returns an object similar to a string, with an additional method foo()
function foo(str) {
  return Object.assign(`${str ?? this}+`, {
    foo
  });
}

var str = "Notepad";
console.log(
  "EXAMPLE - foo(str).foo().toUpperCase():",  
  foo(str).foo().toUpperCase()
);

console.log("---");

console.log("Some issues with this solution:");
console.log("typeof foo(str):", typeof foo(str));
console.log("foo(str).foo():", foo(str).foo());

console.log(
  "You may need to use toString() - foo(str).foo().toString():",
  foo(str).foo().toString()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }
```