# When will this design pattern break?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, d3.js

I was trying to write a plugin for d3.js recently and have been confused with something perhaps trivial. There is an explanation on [d3's website](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) on how to go about creating reusable charts. The pattern looks something like this (only the most important details, full code is [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/time-series-chart.js)):

**Design Pattern 1: From d3 website**

```
function timeSeriesChart() {
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
      ...
      area = d3.svg.area().x(X).y1(Y),
      line = d3.svg.line().x(X).y(Y);

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

      // Convert data to standard representation greedily;
      // this is needed for nondeterministic accessors.
      data = data.map(function(d, i) {
        return [xValue.call(data, d, i), yValue.call(data, d, i)];
      });

      // Update the x-scale.
      ...

      // Update the y-scale.
      ...

      // Select the svg element, if it exists.
      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);
      ...

      // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
      var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
      ...    
  }

  // The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale âˆ˜ xValue.
  function X(d) {      }

  // The x-accessor for the path generator; yScale âˆ˜ yValue.
  function Y(d) {      }

  chart.margin = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
    margin = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.x = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
    xValue = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.y = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
    yValue = _;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

I have no doubt that this pattern is robust especially because it was suggested by the creator of d3 himself. However, I have been using the following pattern for some time without problems before I came across that post (similar to how plugins are created in general):

**Design Pattern 2: General way of creating plugins**

```
(function() {
    var kg = {
        version: '0.1a'
    };

    window.kg = kg;

    kg.chart = {};

    // ==========================================================
    // CHART::SAMPLE CHART TYPE
    // ==========================================================
    kg.chart.samplechart = {

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // CONFIGURATION PARAMETERS
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        WIDTH: 900,
        HEIGHT: 500,
        MARGINS: {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 60,
            padding: 40
        },
        xRange: d3.time.scale(),
        yRange: d3.scale.linear(),
        xAxis: d3.svg.axis(),
        yAxis: d3.svg.axis(),
        data: {},

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // INIT FUNCTION
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        init: function() {
            // Initialize and add graph to the given div
            this.update();
        },

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // Redraws the graph
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        update: function() {
            var parentThis = this;
            var newData = parentThis.data;

            // Continue with adding points/lines to the chart


        },
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // Gets random data for graph demonstration
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        getRandomData: function() {
            // Useful for demo purposes  

        }
    };

    // ==========================================================
    // HELPER FUNCTIONS
    // ==========================================================

}());


// EXAMPLE: This renders the chart. 
kg.chart.samplechart.vis = d3.select("#visualization");
kg.chart.samplechart.data = kg.chart.samplechart.getRandomData();
kg.chart.samplechart.init();​
```

I have been using **Design Pattern 2** for some time without any problems (I agree it is not super clean but I'm working on it). After looking at **Design Pattern 1**, I just felt it had too much redundancy. For instance, look at the last blocks of code that make the internal variables accessible (`chart.margin = function(_) {}` etc.).

Perhaps this is good practice but it makes maintenance cumbersome because this has to be repeated for every different chart type (as seen here in a library called [NVD3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js), currently under development) and increases both development effort and risk of bugs.

I would like to know what kind of serious problems I would face if I continue with my pattern or how my pattern can be improved or made closer to spirit of **Design Pattern 1**. I am trying to avoid changing patterns at this point because that would require a full rewrite and will introduce new bugs into a somewhat stable mini-library. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the last blocks that 'make the internal variables accessible' are doing more than you think - they're more like dynamic accessors. The getter returns the property value, whereas the setter sets the property value then **returns the object itself**. This is done in order to [make the functions chainable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript).

Comment: @ChrisFrancis: Thank you. Is it possible to make *Pattern 2* chainable?

Comment: Certainly - on a very simplistic level, you can take any public method on your plugin that isn't explicitly returning a value (for instance your `init()` method) and make it `return this`. This is essentially the pattern jQuery uses for chaining functions together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you can find your second pattern in the d3 source code.

```
(function(){
...
d3 = {version: "2.9.6"}; // semver
...

d3.svg = {};
d3.svg.arc = function() {
  var innerRadius = d3_svg_arcInnerRadius,
      outerRadius = d3_svg_arcOuterRadius,
...
```

But the components and generators, like scale, axis, area and layout, tend to use the pattern we can call "charts as closures with getter-setter methods" or " higher-order programming 
through configurable functions". You can follow this discussion on the [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/d3-js/6VSl7srPYIo/discussion) for rationale.

Personally, I don't like this redundancy neither, even if it is useful and fairly readable. So  I generate these getters and setters automatically using a custom function:

```
d3.helper.createAccessors = function(visExport) {
    for (var n in visExport.opts) {
        if (!visExport.opts.hasOwnProperty(n)) continue;
        visExport[n] = (function(n) {
            return function(v) {
                return arguments.length ? (visExport.opts[n] = v, this) : visExport.opts[n];
            }
        })(n);
    }
};
```

Which I use like this at the end of my chart module:

```
d3.helper.createAccessors(chart, opts);
```

Where opts is the name of all the public function:

```
var opts = {
            width: 200,
            margin: [5, 0, 20, 0],
            height: 200,
            showPoints: true,
            showAreas: false,
            enableTooltips: true,
            dotSize: 4
        };
```

Here is a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/YPAYz/

Comment: +1 Thank you! I accepted this as an answer but would you mind providing me with a complete example? :) It'll stay here for archival reasons too. Thanks again!

Comment: The example doesn't show a createAccessors function.

Are you missing a ".call" when calling createAccessors?