# How to make chaining method but returning more than 3 value at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

You for sure had seen jquery. Has you know jquery allow you to make chaining of method like this:

```
$('.elements').css({color:'red'}).etc().etc()...
```

But if you notice, that function returns you a array of object(?):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $elements = $('.c').css({color:'red'});
  console.log($elements);
});
```

([Example, see console to see the result](http://jsbin.com/iyuLev/1/edit))

Also the `$` function does as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $elements = $('.c');
  console.log($elements);
});
```

([Example, see console to see the result](http://jsbin.com/OKibivO/1/edit))

Both returns an array and then can keep chaining. How is that possible? Why can keep chaining when it isn't return just `this`(or the object itself)?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript) and he could succesfully add plus sign but that was to an existing string cuz he proto the string object.

Its there any way that i could archive that?

**UPDATE**

I know that it return a jquery object but how can i return my object that contains an array of values and keep chaining with the returned values.

**UPDATE 2**

**What i want to archive**

I have this class and i want a method to return an array of my object whenever if the chaining its over

```
var elements = Enumerable(anArray).Where(function(elements){ return elements != 1 })
```

Here the chainig has over so it must return the elements that satisfy the condition but i want to keep chaingin i just have to do this:

```
elements  = elements.Where(function(elements){ return elements == 1}).Take(3);
```

And keep chaining as looooong as I want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your goal is or what exactly you are asking. Also, they aren't really returning an array, they are returning a jquery object which has sort of an array within it.

Comment: That what im looking, how to return an array of my object and with what ever the values are and keep chaining. I just know to to make it by return this, but not an array

Comment: Why? You can easily filter elements out of a jquery object or even pull a specific element... and loop through each getting values. I think you need to show your end goal for us to be able to help you further.

Comment: @smerny see my update 2 please

Comment: Maybe I'm still confused about what you are trying to do, but it seems like it could be done with a combination of `filter()` and `slice()`? http://jsfiddle.net/5Nv4X/2/

Comment: You did it with Jquery, i want to do it with a my class that i create not with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

`$` doesn't return an array, it returns a [*jQuery object*](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), which is an *array-like* object. I.e. some of its properties have numeric names and it has a `length` property.

Example:

```
var obj = {
    0: element1,
    1: element2,
    find: function() {
        // some logic
        return this; // return a reference to itself for chaining
    },
    length: 2
};
```

Now, a jQuery method doesn't return `this`, it returns a new jQuery object which exposes the same interface (obviously) and hence allows chaining.

If you want to implement chaining yourself, you have to do the same: Either return `this` or a new instance of your object and initialize it with the data the current object has.

Example:

```
function Constr(data) {
    this.data = data || {};
}

Contr.prototype.chain = function() {
    // do stuff
    console.log(this.data);
    return new Constr(this.data);
    // or return this;
};

var obj = new Constr({foo: 'bar'});
obj.chain().chain().chain();
```

Comment: Yes, the example I provided as example also fits for this use case. Again: Either return `this` or a new instance of your "class".

Answer (score 0):

a jquery object is actually a collection of html objects so when a function returns a jquery object it's actually returning more than one element.

```
var ChainableObject = {
    data: [],
    where: function(fn){
       //doStuff with this.data
       return this;
    },
    take: function(n){
       //doStuff with this.data
       return this;
    },
    // and so on
    //.........
}
```

Comment: Oh men, you saved me!!!! That whas the answer!! I'd accept you answer but i dont have reputation enougt to :(