# making a function in an object chainable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve a chainable object, but cannot figure out how I can do this within a function.

This is how I would like it to work:

`$donate.ga('testing').go(value);`

My object currently looks like this:

```
var $donate = {
    ga: function (value) {

    }
};
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300844/what-does-return-this-do-within-a-javascript-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make chainable function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to make each function to return the instance of the object:

```
var $donate = {
    ga: function (value) {
        // logic
        return this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript). You must simply return the object in your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the Object like that:

```
var $donate = {
    ga: function (value) {
       //after some computation
       return this;
    },
    go: function(val) {
       //after some computation
       return this;
    }
};
```

If you don't return this (this is a reference to the current Object), you either return undefined or something else and your method defined in your Object is simply out of scope (**unknown**).

Answer (score 0):

you have to `return this;` in each sub function before closing it.
for example
Your code

```
var $donate = {
    ga: function (value) {
       //perform your code here
       return this;  // <--- Dont forget to use this before closing the function nest
    },
    go: function(val) {
       //perform your code here
       return this;  // <--- Dont forget to use this before closing the function nest
    }
};
```