# How to create a function that is sintactically different

Tags: javascript, function

For example in the promises:

```
New Promise(function(){}).then(function(){});
```

*Where is the important thing? , in **the syntax** of* `.then`

, so how i can create a function that can be applied in other function with `"."` (dot operator)

**per example(pseudocode) :**

```
function doSomething(a,b) {return a+b}.myOwnFunction(function(){
  console.log("Function applied in another function with DOT operator");
});
```

Comment: Markdown party? ;)

Comment: `new Promise(function(){})` does not return a function, it returns a javascript object that has a `then` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the result of `doSomething()` call must be an object with `myOwnFunction` property of `function` type. It is possible for example via the next approach:

```
function Wrapper(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
Wrapper.prototype.myOwnFunction = function() {
  console.log("The caller value is " + this.value);
};
```

And then

```
function doSomething(a, b) { return new Wrapper(a + b) };
doSomething(1, 2).myOwnFunction(); // The caller value is 3
```

or

```
function doSomething(a, b) { return a + b; }
new Wrapper(doSomething(1, 2)).myOwnFunction(); //The caller value is 3
```

Comment: I think it would be more in accordance with the question if `Wrapper` took a function - not a value - (i.e. `function Wrapper (f) { this.f = f; } Wrapper.prototype.myOwnFunction = function () { console.log("The function returns " + this.f(); };`) and you wrote `var doSomething = function (a, b) { return a + b; }` followed by `new Wrapper(doSomething).myOwnFunction()`.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 But still where should I pass real values for a, b params? I see only this way with your approach: `new Wrapper(function() { return doSomething(1, 2); }).myOwnFunction();`

Comment: Oh yeah, of course.  They would either have to be made up inside `myOwnFunction` or passed as parameters to it.

Comment: Also, `myOwnFunction` could be written as a top-level function like so: `var myOwnFunction = function (doSomething, f2) { doSomething(1, 2); f2(); /* etc */ }` and never return an object or use dot notation.  It is hard to say, without knowing what the OP wants `myOwnFunction` to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is something called "[chainable functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript)".

**Example 1**

Consider the example below:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var index = array.filter(cut).indexOf(3);

console.log(index);

function cut(n){
    return n > 1;
}
```

The variable `index` returns the result of the function `array.filter(...).indexOf(...)`.

But how does it work? Let's break it down.

**1. Initializing an array**

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
// A variable `array`is created with the value of an array `[1, 2, 3]`.
```

**2. Using `Array` method [`filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)**

```
array.filter(cut)
// This function returns an array of value [2, 3];
```

**3. Chaining `Array` method [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) to `filter`**

```
array.filter(cut).indexOf(3);
// equals to [2, 3].indexOf(3)
// returns the value 1.
```

So why can we chain the function `indexOf` to `filter`?

Because `array.filter()` returns an array, and `indexOf` and `filter` are methods that are under the same [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) from `Array` constructor.

**Example 2**

Similarly, this example using `String` constructor will work:

```js
var string = 'This is a string';
var newString = string.substring(0, 4).toUpperCase();

console.log(newString);
```

Because [`string.substring(...)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) returns a string and [`toUpperCase()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) is a method from `String` constructor.

**Example 3**

This is a little bit trickier.

```js
var string = 'This is a string';
var newString = string.split(' ').indexOf('is');

console.log(newString);
```

Now, [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) is a `String` method but `indexOf()` is an `Array` method. Then why does this work?

Because `split()` method returns an *array* value. So, you need a method from `Array` constructor to chain it.

**How to create a chainable function?**

You can create your own constructor function with its own prototype.

```js
var a = undefined;

// The constructor
var Example = function(string){
    this.value = string;
}

// The prototypes
Example.prototype.addString = function(string){
    this.value += ' ' + string;
    return this;
};
Example.prototype.becomeArray = function(){
    return this.value.split(' ');
};

// Creating an instance of the constructor
a = new Example('This is a');
console.log(a.constructor === Example);

// Chaining methods from its prototype
a = new Example('This is a').addString('string').becomeArray();
console.log(a);
```

Of course this is an oversimplified example. And there is many other ways to achieve the result.

But then that is out of scope of this question.